# React Native (or React) listen to the style changes for the dark mode in separate ts modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, rendering

Goal: Implement *dark mode* in react native application.
A little introduction to the system:
File structure:

- Profile.ts
- ProfileCss.ts
- constants.ts

In my application in order to separate styles from components, I moved them into .ts files and exported as modules.
Example of **StyleCss.ts**:

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Window, FixedCSS, hsize, wsize} from '../../entities/constants';
    
export default StyleSheet.create({
    loading: {
        backgroundColor: FixedCSS.Colors.MainBackgroundColor,
    }
    ...
});
```

All style-related constant values stored in **constants.ts** such as Colors, LineHeights, and etc. Also **constants.ts** contains a class called **FixedCSS** which has static properties:

```
export class FixedCSS {
    static isDark = true;

    static Colors = {
        // Main Colors
        RootColor: FixedCSS.isDark ? '#FF6666' : '#FF6666',
        MainBackgroundColor: FixedCSS.isDark ? '#050505' : '#FFFFFF',
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

*isDark* property of FixedCSS is supposed to be changed with the help of Switch component in Profile.ts

```
<Switch
    value={darkMode}
    onValueChange={value => {
        this.setState({darkMode: value});
    }}
/>
```

The problem: How can I change *isDark* property in FixedCSS class so that it will affect the appearance of components. The most problematic aspect is that StyleCSS.ts files do not reflect to the change of *isDark* property in FixedCSS class, as they are exported only once when js bundle gets created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a `static` property of a class is not going to trigger re-renders the way that it's supposed to.  This needs to make use of `state` somehow.  I recommend a theme `Context`. You could use one context or have separate contexts for controlling `isDarkMode` and providing the CSS, which is what I am doing here.

In order to export a value only once but have that value stay current, the exported value can be a function rather than a constant.  I am making the fixed CSS be a function of `isDark` and the individual component styles be a function of `FixedCSS`.

**constants.ts**

```
export const createFixedCSS = (isDark: boolean) => ({
  isDark,
  Colors: {
    // Main Colors
    RootColor: isDark ? "#FF6666" : "#FF6666",
    MainBackgroundColor: isDark ? "#050505" : "#FFFFFF"
    ...
  }
  ...
});

export type FixedCSS = ReturnType<typeof createFixedCSS>;

export const IS_DARK_DEFAULT = false;
```

**cssContext.ts**

```
// context to provide the FixedCSS object, which also includes isDark
const FixedCSSContext = createContext(createFixedCSS(IS_DARK_DEFAULT));

// context to provide a function for switching modes
// type Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>> allows for setting based on previous value
type SetModeContextValue = Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;

// needs an initial value that fits the type signature
const SetModeContext = createContext<SetModeContextValue>(() => {
    throw new Error(
      "cannot set `isDark` outside of a `DarkModeContext` Provider"
    );
});

// combine both contexts into one Provider component
export const CSSProvider: FC<{}> = ({ children }) => {
  // store the isDark state
  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(IS_DARK_DEFAULT);

  // update the FixedCSS when isDark changes
  // I'm not sure if memoizing is actually necessary here?
  const FixedCSS = useMemo(() => createFixedCSS(isDark), [isDark]);

  return (
    <SetModeContext.Provider value={setIsDark}>
      <FixedCSSContext.Provider value={FixedCSS}>
        {children}
      </FixedCSSContext.Provider>
    </SetModeContext.Provider>
  );
};

// I prefer to export the hooks rather than the contexts themselves
export const useFixedCSS = () => useContext(FixedCSSContext);
export const useSetMode = () => useContext(SetModeContext);

// helper hook for `StyleCss.ts` files
// takes the makeStyles factory function and turns it into a style object by accessing the  FixedCSS context
export const useStyleFactory = <T extends StyleSheet.NamedStyles<T>>(
  factory: (css: FixedCSS) => T
): T => {
  const FixedCSS = useFixedCSS();
  return useMemo(() => factory(FixedCSS), [FixedCSS, factory]);
};
```

**ProfileCss.ts**

```
export const makeStyles = (FixedCSS: FixedCSS) => StyleSheet.create({
    loading: {
        backgroundColor: FixedCSS.Colors.MainBackgroundColor,
    }
});
```

**Profile.ts**

```
const DarkModeToggle = () => {
  // access isDark from global FixedCSS
  const {isDark} = useFixedCSS();
  
  // access update callback
  const setIsDark = useSetMode();

  return (
    <Switch
      value={isDark}
      onValueChange={setIsDark}
    />
  )
}

const Profile = () => {

  // pass the imported `makeStyles` to the hook and get stateful styles object
  const styles = useStyleFactory(makeStyles);

  return (
    <View>
      <DarkModeToggle/>
      <View style={styles.loading}/>
    </View>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-mode-theme-context-4k738?file=/src/App.tsx) (all in one file)